# Centering a mediaelement according to the aspect ratio

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

So, I've got this mediaelement, which I want to appear in the middle of the screen, 20 pixels away from each edge, and when it's width gets to 600, it stops expanding and stays where it is. I've got the following XAML to get exactly what I want:

```
<Grid x:Name="video">
    <MediaElement x:Name="player" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Margin="20,0" MaxWidth="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

The only problem is that the VerticalAlignment property seems to always be set to "Stretch". How can I fix this? I've tried using a viewbox, which works flawlessly, except I then get overly large or small TransportControls. I've also tried putting the mediaelement inside another grid with centered alignments, but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found how to fix this, by keeping a constant aspect ratio of 16/9:

XAML:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="player_SizeChanged" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="1" MinHeight="1" Margin="30" MaxWidth="1000" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <MediaElement x:Name="player" Margin="0">
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private void player_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Grid).Height = (e.NewSize.Width * 0.5625);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

> 20 pixels away from each edge.

But in your code you defined `Margin="20,0"`, if you read the [FrameworkElement.Margin property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.margin.aspx), you will find the useage `<frameworkElement Margin="left+right,top+bottom"/>`. With your code, this usage makes your `MediaElement` stretch in the vertical orientation.

If you use the [Live Visual Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) to get a real-time view of your running XAML code, you will find, when you use the code `Margin="20,0"`, the `MediaElement` is like this:
[image]

And if you use the code `Margin="20"`, the `MediaElement` is like this:
[image]

The dashed red border in each picture stands for the `MediaElement` control.

Comment: Yeah, I know, this was a typo. But the actual problem was keeping the aspect ratio. But never mind, I found how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Pivot Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="LightGray">
            <PivotItem Header="Formulas">
                <Grid>
                    <GridView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF983636">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>Two</x:String>
                    <x:String>Three</x:String>
                    <x:String>Four</x:String>
                </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>

        </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

The key here is  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" on the GridView.

[image]

The HorizontalAlignment="Center" on the VariableSizedWrapGrid inside the ItemsPanelTemplate inside the Gridview; should do the trick which will always keep the content centered regardless of the width of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help; but I think you might have misunderstood my post: I'm trying to center a mediaelement in the center of a Grid, not a GridView :/